# C++ Dealing with array of pointers of structs

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, struct

I have to following struct that's used in the fuction below:

```
struct ll_ftse {
    int index=0;
    ll_ftse* next=NULL;
};

func() {
    ll_ftse **g;
    ll_ftse *aux;

    tam = 6 / epsilon;

    g = new ll_ftse*[tam];

    for(i=0;i<tam;i++)
        g[i] = NULL;

    (...)

    aux = g[tam/2+diff];
}
```

In that last statement I get a compiling error. "error: invalid types 'simulacao::ll_ftse**[double]' for array subscript"

'diff' is another var declared in the beginning. And 'epsilon' is a globally declared var.

I just can't figure it out! Any clues?

Comment: What's the types of `tam` and `diff`? It seems you are trying to use a `double` as array index, and you can't do that.

Comment: I suggest you learn what types are, that thing you posted isn't C++.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, if I had to guess I'd say `tam` is an integer (since `new ll_ftse*[tam]` compiles) and `diff` is a double (since the error is plenty clear). However it's not worth the effort to guess if he can't even paste the type from his own code.

Comment: Well yes, the compiler already gave you a pretty good clue: "invalid types [...] for array subscript".  Evidently the expression `tam/2+diff` has type `double`, whereas you need an integer type.  One way to get what you want might be to change that expression to `(int)(tam/2+diff)`, but it's unclear whether that's actually correct.  Overall, it is very suspicious that you are computing array sizes and indexes as `double`s.

Comment: Yeah... I was so concentrated with the pointers stuff and didn't realize diff was double. Put a cast to int and worked fine. Thanks a lot!